# In TradingView Pine Script, How to to identify high/low for a specific date and bar-index of the same high/low candle

Tags: tradingview-api

In TradingView Pine Script, In 5 Minute Time frame, How to to identify high/low candle for a specific date and bar-index of the same high/low 5 min candle

Not sure. How to get this

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you share a picture of what you want ?